# The input is a list and the output is in the form of a nested dictionary in a list

Tags: json, python-3.x

Input:

```
input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe']
```

Output format:

```
out_dict=[{'name':'1.exe',
           'children':[{'name':'2.exe',
                        'children':[{'name':'3.exe                                                                  
                                     'children':[{'name':'4.exe'}]}}}]
```

The input is the a list as above mentioned and we have to obtain the output in the format as mentioned in the above lines.

I tried using nested for loops but it isn't working. How can we implement `JSON` in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe']

def split(data):
    try:
        first_value = data[0]
        data = [{'name': first_value, 'children': split(data[1:])} if split(data[1:]) != [] else {'name': first_value}]
        return data
    except:
        return data

print (split(input_list))
```

output:

```
[{'name': '1.exe', 'children': 
        [{'name': '2.exe', 'children': 
                [{'name': '3.exe', 'children': 
                         [{'name': '4.exe'}]}]}]}]
```

code which is a little bit more easier to understand (with explinations):

```
input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe']
def split(input_list):
  if len(input_list) == 0:
      return input_list # if there is no data return empty list
  else: # if we have elements
      first_value = input_list[0] # first value
      if split(input_list[1:]) != []: # data[1:] will return a list with all values except the first value
          input_list = [{'name':first_value ,'children': split(input_list[1:])}]
          return input_list  # return after the last recursion is called
      else:
          input_list = [{'name': first_value}]  
          return input_list

print (split(input_list))
```

output:

```
[{'name': '1.exe', 'children': 
        [{'name': '2.exe', 'children': 
                [{'name': '3.exe', 'children': 
                         [{'name': '4.exe'}]}]}]}]
```

or:

```
input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe']

def split(input_list):
    if input_list:
        head, *tail = input_list  # This is a nicer way of doing head, tail = data[0], data[1:]
        if split(tail) != []:
            return [{'name': head, 'children':split(tail)}]
        else:
            return [{'name': head}]
    else:
        return {}

print (split(input_list))
```

> **Convert from Python to JSON:**
>
> ```
> import json
>
> # a Python object (dict):
> x = {
>   "name": "John",
>   "age": 30,
>   "city": "New York"
> }
>
> # convert into JSON:
> y = json.dumps(x)
>
> # the result is a JSON string:
> print(y)
> ```
>
> JSON is a syntax for storing and exchanging data. Convert from Python
>   to JSON If you have a Python object, you can convert it into a JSON
>   string by using the json.dumps() method.

```
import json
input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe']

def split(input_list):
    try:
        first_value = input_list[0]
        input_list = {'name': first_value, 'children': split(input_list[1:])} if split(input_list[1:]) != [] else {'name': first_value}
        return input_list
    except:
        return input_list

data = split(input_list)
print (json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: we have to implement json and dictionaries using python for this

Comment: what you mean with  implement json and dictionaries? if you have :input_list=['1.exe','2.exe','3.exe','4.exe'] this is  code which will generate output that you mentioned in your post: Output format @SarthakPundir